# How to set git branch to state of another branch

Tags: git

I wish to set my `master` branch to the exact state that my `tmp` branch is at.

There is incorrect changes committed on the master branch, but even after merging the tmp branch those mistakes still persists.

I've tried (on master):

```
git checkout tmp
git reset --hard xxxxxx
```

but that also fails. It's unfortunate that git is this hard to do something so simple. What must I do to fix my master branch?

**EDIT**
I've tried to find the problem and it's the one highlighted that is wrong. It seems I shouldn't have done that reverse. (My temp branch doesn't have that reverse, which is why it's probably working.) So how do I reverse a revert?

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Undo a few commits or change a branch to look like another branch?

Comment: @NilsWerner `master` has an incorrect commit, but I don't know which one. The files in `tmp` stayed correct and continued to be dev'd. Now when merging `tmp` to `master`, the incorrect commit overwrite the state of the `tmp` files.

Comment: Merging will not help as it will try to merge changes from **both branches**.

Comment: I am confused why resetting `master` to `tmp` will not help. After doing that, both branches should look exactly like `tmp` did before... What does `master` look like after the `reset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just "revert the revert"

```
git revert <SHA1 of 'Revert "user profiles filtering"'>
```

Explanation: A `revert` does not undo the entire history until a certain commit is reached but instead takes the commit-patch and applies the "inverse patch" to your current revision.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Had some conflicts, but nothing I couldn't figure out.